Minimum Bend Radius of a FR-4 PCB
How much tension from flexure can the standard FR-4 pcb endure?
I know this will be a factor of the number of layers and width of each layer, but I couldn't find anything online on how to calculate or ballpark the minimal bending radius of the standard rigid PCB
By minimal bending radius, I am looking for the amount of tension it can withstand without damaging the copper layer over time.
An example would be a PCB mounted unevenly forcing the PCB to flex with some amount between said screws

What are you trying to achieve?

A method to determine if a pcb will take damaging from a certain bend, and also to what extent or time frame said damage would occur

Is this about an unpopulated PCB only or are there also components on the PCB?

In theory I would prefer for both, but maybe way different rules apply for a populated pcb? Again it's only damage to the print, not damage to any components on the print

See this https://www.we-online.com/en/products/printed-circuit-boards/flex-solutions/semiflex

Yes the rules are different for populated PCBs. Some components (ceramic capacitors for example) are significantly more fragile than the PCB you might solder them to. These components will fail long before the PCB does when flexed.

FR-4 is not one specific material, but rather a grade of material. So even ignoring the problems with the laminar structure, it will depend on the manufacturer of your FR-4.

I would be more worried about solder joints failing from the PCB flexing than a failure in the PCB itself.

This is the reason structural engineers and Finite Element Analysis (FEA) engineers make those big salaries .

A populated FR-4 board under bending stresses will fail the components well before you damage the copper traces.  I work with a lot of automotive PCAs and we regulary have to qualify new designs by measuring the microstrain at the board surface during assembly and handling.
There are various specs and standards, but typically around 1000 microstrain is in the ballpark of limits.  What you risk by going higher is cracking MLCCs in particular.  And that is a very nasty failure mode, because a cracked capacitor is likely to pass functional tesing and work fine for a brief period, but then fail as a short circuit later.  There are flexible termination caps that help mitigate this but resistors and ICs also have their limits on microstrain.

This is a very difficult question to answer with anything other than "it depends!".
The whole thing (both PCB and Components) is a laminated structure. The layers involved in a specific instance will likely play a significant part in whatever figure you get out of any experiments. When I say "layers", I'm referring to the weave, copper, resins, adhesives, solder, components, conformal coating, etc... (not just "Core", "Prepeg", "Copper").
Adding any repeated flex, vibration, or shock into the mix may quite well have catastrophic results.

An example would be a PCB mounted unevenly forcing the PCB to flex with some amount between said screws

I'd suggest you aim as close to zero as you can reasonably achieve!
Thinner boards (e.g: 0.8mm) have some tolerance to flex without splintering or failing, but that drops off very quickly as the thickness goes up (e.g: doubling to the typical 1.6mm).
To prove the point, I just flexed some scrap rigid PCBs for you... for some very approximate figures, hand held, and trying to approximately match the force by feel. Both boards are approx 22mm wide, and held at approx 100mm from the free end. Force is appled to the free end, and the flex distance measured.

0.8mm thick: ~30mm flex
1.6mm thick: ~7mm flex


It depends on:

The thickness of your PCB
The number of layers, and their shape.
Populated components
The shape of the PCB.
More


In general, we don't tend to design our PCBs to bend. FR4 is actually pretty strong stuff, so it's unlikely that you'd screw in a PCB and accidentally damage something. Whether the copper will survive is another big 'it depends', but generally for a single static bend I'd be more worried about components popping off if it was extreme before the copper breaking.
Remember also that 3 points define a plane, so regardless of what you're mounting too, if you only use 3 screws you'll not bend the PCB.
I can't imagine accidently breaking a square PCB with a manual screw process, I think you'd start to notice how much force the screw was taking, though I'm sure it would be possible with the right PCB geometry. I wonder if there's a specific case behind your question, rather than a pure hypothetical. If there is, do go ahead and ask a new question that's more specific to what you've got going on.
